# Portable way to push arguments onto the call stack (C++)

Tags: c++, parameters, callstack

I'm writing a small scripting language.

I am looking for a portable C++ way to push parameters onto the call stack so that my function will read them in normally.

Is this possible?  It has to compile in Visual Studio, XCode, and Android Studio-- preferably using asm embedded in the C++ (having an external assembler file is not an option)

Comment: What do you really need? Do you want to call functions defined in ASM from C++ or what? There is no access to the stack in C++, but there are architecture-defined ABIs that are followed when calling external functions. The parameters are generally passed in registers and not on stack. For details google for "<your architecture> <your os> calling conventions".

Comment: Why do you need that for an interpreter?

Comment: "Scripting languages" generally do not push arguments onto the "call stack". Or at least, not the *same* call stack the C/C++/assembly/etc uses. They generally have a "stack" of some kind, but structurally, this is an actual object in the C++ world which has data stored within it.

Comment: @NicolBolas The purposes is to call MyFunction(param,param,param) on the script side and also call the function MyFunction(param,param,param) on the C++ side.  AngelScript does this, but requires including asm files into the project.  I was merely asking here if there was some opposite version of va_args that could be used to fill the stack instead of just read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there’s no portable ways.

Also, asm embedded in the C++ is not portable, MS Visual studio doesn’t support it when compiling for Win64.

One approach around this is invent some ABI on top of C or C++, suitable for your particular use case and script language. This can be done in portable way and without assembly.

See how MS did it with their VBScript, IDispatch, and VARIANT data type.

I’m not saying you must stick with OLE automation ABI, that was just an example. E.g. if you only passing several float values to your functions, you can do following:
`int Invoke(IDFunc func, int argc, const float* argv)`, make your script runtime resolve function names into IDFunc identifiers, fill arguments array, and call the Invoke function. Then on the C++ side of the interop, call the correct function. You no longer need to manually push arguments, you only need to dispatch the function call, and there’re many approaches for that, macros, templates, code gen, or some combination of them.

P.S. The `IDFunc` data type is int16 for MS OLE, but you can make it to be a pointer to something instead, might help with implementation.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but this is the right answer.  I was hoping there was some hidden opposite version of va_args that I had just never run into before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way of doing that (that i know of), because a "call stack" is not a portable thing. One machine may have different call stacks implementations then the other, for example PIC18 devices have separate call stack and variable stack, while x86 share use same stack for functions and variables and return values (in very simple words...).
Probably the best would be to create a separate solution (macro or function) for every architecture and compiler you need to support and then using proprocessor conditional structure to differentiate between them. When using gcc compiler you may use [asm keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and when running on x86 architecture you may use [push instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html) to push data onto the stack.
Then the (semi-) *portable* way is to provide an API which implementation changes between architectures and compilers, like that:

```
// for gcc and clang compiler for x86 architecture
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__i386__)
#define PUSH_VALUE_ONTO_THE_CALL_STACK(val)  do{ \
/* this will break your code, dont use this */ \
int __v = (val); \
__asm__("push %0" : "r" (__v)); \
} while(0)
// for  Visual Studio compiler x86 architecture
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(__i386__)
#define PUSH_VALUE_ONTO_THE_CALL_STACK(val)  do{ \
/* this will break your code, dont use this */ \
__asm mov eax, val; \
__asm push eax; \
} while(0)
// add more
#elif defined(__PREDEFINED_MACRO_FOR_COMPILER) && defined(__PREDEFINED_MACRO_FOR_ARCHITECTURE)
#define PUSH_VALUE_ONTO_THE_CALL_STACK(val) /* implementation */
// when implementation is missing, issue a error
#else
#error Implementation PUSH_VALUE_ONTO_THE_CALL_STACK not found for Your architecture and compiler.
#endif

int main(void) {
      // identical usage/api between compilers and architectures
      PUSH_VALUE_ONTO_THE_CALL_STACK(5);
      return 0;
 }
```

Hope that sets you on the right track.
Also: XCode is just the name of an IDE, I think XCode uses clang by default. Android Studio [may use clang or gcc](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++ 17, the portable way is [std::apply](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

[Here’s a demo](https://github.com/Const-me/MicroScript), see Engine\Function.hpp source file.